# Automatically move source code files to project folder in Visual Studio 2008/2010 which are added as link and residing outside the project folder

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, ide, projects-and-solutions

Is there a plugin/trick/macro for visual studio which automatically moves all files present outside a project directory and added as link, to the project directory and alters the location of the file in the project itself?

```
|--Project1
          |--File1.vb REM: already inside the project folder
|--File2.vb REM: outside the project folder and added as link to project1.
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

```
|--Project1
          |--File1.vb REM: remains as it is
          |--File2.vb REM: now moved to project1 directory.
```

Comment: If you want to automate this, and are ready to implement it by yourself, have a look to Visual Studio automation (envDTE) or to Roslyn CTP (very cool, but just a preview for now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should not be too hard to write such a tool by yourself. The project files are just XML files, and references to source files look like this:

With links:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="..\Path_To_External_File\SourceFile.vb">
     <Link>SourceFile.vb</Link>
  </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
```

Same without links:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="SourceFile.vb" />
</ItemGroup>
```

So write a very simple program or script which reads all the project files to be processed, loop over all `<Compile>` items, make a copy of the source file or just move it to the desired location, and adapt the XML of the project file accordingly. If you have  ever programmed some XML processing beforehand, using, for example, the`XMLDocument` class, then this should be implemented in a few hours (at maximum).

One final remark: you may (or may not) have to to deal with the case where the same files is referenced from different projects.

Comment: Now I thought I was gonna "reinvent the wheel". Somebody must have thought of this before me.

Comment: A general solution needs probably more thoughts in how to deal with the same file referenced more than once from different projects.

Comment: I would then make copies of that file in each folder or even better not make any changes to that file. Anyway did you come across any tool which does this job?

Comment: @SohamDasgupta: if I would know such a tool, I would have given a you a link instead of my suggestion to write your own one. But concerning build scripts: not every problem is solved by the VS builtin features, but since MSBUILD scripts are readable XML, such problems are easy to solve.

Comment: I just started writing a Visual Studio addin.

Answer (score 3):

Visual does the copy during compiling already if it's what you're looking for. On the other hand, if you want to really add the files, but not as a link, I pretty sure there is no native trick in VS for this.

Comment: Any plugins that would do the job?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, but I don't know everything ^^

Comment: What I'm sure of : if you really want to correct the fact that adding your files as link was a mistake, you should edit the title of your question to reflect that, it clearly don't say that.

Comment: And a question : do you want to just add the file as File in Project1, but without moving the file, or you also want the file to be moving in the folder ?

Comment: Yes you are right I want to move the file as well for organizing purpose.